# How to base my ASP.NET website out of a specific URL directory?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've got IIS 7 serving up my ASP.NET MVC website. It's the only site that I have configured in IIS. When I access the site, the site is based out of the root URL directory. For example, my site would be accessed like this: http://example.com/index.html

How can I configure the ASP.NET site to be prefixed by a specific URL directory? I'd like it to be something like this: http://example.com/application/index.html

Is this something I do in the ASP.NET configuration or within IIS itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an "Application" for your site (right click on your web site in IIS Manager and choose "Add Application") and give it the directory name that you want.  This way you can have, for example, multiple applications under the same domain e.g. http://example.com/application1/whatever and http://example.com/application2/whatever.

This article describes the differences between Sites, Applications and Virtual Directories:

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: When I create a website, I have to select a directory where the site exists already. If I add a virtual directory, it looks like I have to select the same directory again and it just adds it to the existing website project. I was looking at virtual directories but they didn't seem like to correct way to do this, to me. It seemed kind of like a round-about solution.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that you can add `Application`s to each `Website`. Makes me wonder what the difference between the two are, now. I have the same website code selected for both the `Website` and the `Application`. I'm assuming I have this configured incorrectly, and that I only need the code selected in 1 spot.

Comment: This is how every organisation I've worked for does it.  I would've thought you would have something else served up for the base domain and then the virtual directory for a specific application.  Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: Applications work too... I'm not sure how different this is to a virtual directory?

Comment: I took another look at how my own applications are configured in IIS and they are actually Applications.  I've edited my answer to reflect this.